# Sending data in json object in angular post request

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on angular post and try to send a post request with two json object with two diff form  bodies in one post request.I have two form but i need to submit the data in one post request.

I and need the post request data in this way.

```
{
  "detail": {
    "status": "class",
    "service_type": "online",
  },
  "subject": {
    "start_date": "2022-06-28",
    "end_date": "2022-06-29",
    "start_time": "10:00",
    "end_time": "12:30",
  }
}
```

But After getting the data i am trying to create json object like this. Is this right way to do so?

```
const body = [{"detail":{"status":"BrakePad","service_type":"online"},"subject":{"start_date": "2022-06-28",} }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payload you send and the one you expect to send are not the same : you send an array, but you ask us to send an object.

Your payload should then be :

```js
const body = {
  detail:{
    status: "BrakePad",
    service_type:"online"
  },
  subject: {
    start_date: "2022-06-28"
  } 
};

// Send with 
this.http.post('YOUR_URL', body).subscribe();
```

Comment: Can you  please tell me how i can push an value to object?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was confused high appreciated for the help. People make it duplicate or mark it delete. But you help my question.

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra `,` in you object.

It should be `[{"detail":{"status":"BrakePad","service_type":"online"},"subject":{"start_date": "2022-06-28"} }]`.

I'm not sure why you are putting the single object into an array. You can post it as `{"detail":{"status":"BrakePad","service_type":"online"},"subject":{"start_date": "2022-06-28"} }` if the array is not needed.

You will also want to convert your array to a string before posting it using `JSON.stringify`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: There's no "etra comma", JS can handle that without issue, and you don't need to convert to string before sending.

Comment: @MGX am i sending in right way?